# Not able to loading properties file from classpath

Tags: java, spring

I am running jar file using **java -classpath "file_name.properties"  -jar file_name.jar.** This jar contains spring bean classes and xml's. I configured file_name.properties file in spring xml using PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer bean like below.

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
    <property name="locations">  
        <list>  
            <value>classpath:file_name.properties</value>
       </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

But I'm getting `FileNotFoundException` like below.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [einvoice-spring.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
        at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:153)
```

So please help me fix this issue.

Thanks,
Narsi

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without the list tags ?

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer">
  <property name="location" value="classpath:path/to/service.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `java -classpath "full-path-of-folder-that-contains-resources" -jar jar-to-run.jar`
example: `java -classpath C:\java\example -jar example.jar`

**EDIT:** alternative solution

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceholderConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">  
  <property name="locations">  
    <list>  
        <value>file:${config-location}/file_name.properties</value>
   </list>  
  </property>  
</bean>
```

and use `java -Dconfig-location=absolute_path_to_config_folder -jar your.jar`

Comment: spring boot application?

Comment: No, we are developing standalone application using spring IOC

Comment: maybe a bit late... sorry